# Does this definition of the Fourier intensity measure make sense?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\epsilon_n$ be a sequence in $\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb Z_+}$.
EDIT: to make the question easier, assume that $\epsilon_n$ is just the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) with symbols $1$ and $-1$.

We define partial Fourier amplitudes

$$G_N(q)=\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} \epsilon_n \exp(inq)$$

and the corresponding intensities

$$S_N(q)=\frac{1}{N}|G_N(q)|^2$$

Does the limit

$$d\mu(q)=\lim_{N\to\infty} \left[ S_N(q) \frac{dq}{2\pi}\right]$$

make sense? How do we prove rigorously that it exists?

For context, this definition of $d\mu(q)$ (the Fourier intenstiy measure) comes from (2.3) in the following paper:

> Luck, J. M. "Cantor spectra and scaling of gap widths in
>   deterministic aperiodic systems." Physical Review B 39, no. 9 (1989):
>   5834.

This paper can be found [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.39.5834) (paywalled)

Comment: Do the Fourier coefficients of $S_N(q)$ converge as $N \to \infty$ ? If the $\epsilon_n$ are a realization of some stationnary process then the coefficients of $S_N(q)$ converge to the autocorrelation and $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N(q)$ converges in the sense of distributions

Comment: @reuns The paper has some complicated condition on the $\epsilon$. I have modified the question to the special case I am interested in, but I don't think it is a stationary point process.